# prevent double datas in select box

Tags: php, jquery, html

Here is my HTML + PHP :

```
<select name="type" class="form-control form-update-user" id="type" tabindex=1>
   <option selected="selected"><?php echo $thirds['type']; ?></option>
   <option value="CLIENT">CLIENT</option>
   <option value="AFFRETE">AFFRETE</option>
   <option value="DEPOT">DEPOT</option>
</select>
```

I am using JQUERY as Framework for javascript.

My problem is probably simple. But how can I prevent selectbox to have the same data multiple times? For example, if

```
$third['type'] = "AFFRETE"
```

Then, I will have one time AFFRETE as selected value, and again this value in my select box. I tried to remove the selected value with ready function in javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#type option:selected").remove();
})

</script>
```

But then I have another value selected... logical.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this directly in PHP.  Check the array value before adding the element as an option:

```
<select name="type" class="form-control form-update-user" id="type" tabindex=1>
   <?php if (!in_array($thirds['type'], array('CLIENT', 'AFFRETE', 'DEPOT'))): ?>
       <option selected="selected"><?php echo $thirds['type']; ?></option>
   <?php endif; ?>
   <option value="CLIENT">CLIENT</option>
   <option value="AFFRETE">AFFRETE</option>
   <option value="DEPOT">DEPOT</option>
</select>
```

Or maybe you're looking for:

```
<?php $options = array('CLIENT', 'AFFRETE', 'DEPOT'); ?>
<select name="type" class="form-control form-update-user" id="type" tabindex=1>
    <?php foreach ($options as $option): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $option; ?>"
        <?php if ($option === $thirds['type']): ?>
            selected="selected"
        <?php endif;
        ><?php echo $option; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: The problem is that here, you don't remove a value which is the same as the selected one. Indeed, the code then could be as you can see below, but I thought I could find something smarter.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Except that I wanted to do this in JS, so I didn't thought about PHP. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
<select name="type" class="form-control form-update-user" id="type" tabindex=1>
  <option value="CLIENT" <?php echo $thirds['type']=='CLIENT'?'selected=selected':''; ?>>CLIENT</option>
  <option value="AFFRETE" <?php echo $thirds['type']=='AFFRETE'?'selected=selected':''; ?>>AFFRETE</option>
  <option value="DEPOT" <?php echo $thirds['type']=='DEPOT'?'selected=selected':''; ?>>DEPOT</option>
</select>
```

Remember that this is a quick and dirty way to do this. Prefer making a loop creating the options, instead of hardcoding it.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I will try to make a loop.